# Preferred method of communication from the inside of a breaker box

Tags: ethernet, wifi, power-line-communication

I am developing a smart meter that would measure 3-phase current on the main circuit breaker (residential or industrial) and would broadcast the data to an MQTT server.

My question is: what is the optimal method of sending data to a computer network? A breaker box is usually a very noisy environment and is usually also surrounded by a metal case (Faraday cage).

My three options that I can think of right now are: WiFi, ethernet or PLC (power line communication). Which one would be the best for such an application?

WiFi would probably be the easiest one to do but the range would probably be too limited to be usable in any sort of real environment.

Ethernet I have heard has some sort of problem with EMI when it is close to power lines and it would probably be very impractical for a lot of people to run an ethernet cable to their electricity box as well, I would imagine.

PLC would maybe be the a reasonable option but I dont know if it works well on high current lines like 30 A+ and in an industrial environment.

Which one of these options would you recommend is the best and if none of them are any good, is there another method?

Comment: Your question is more of a consulting "what could i pick" type of of question where there is no correct answer. Try discussing subjects like this on forums.

Comment: Commercial devices I’ve seen have a cellular modem. Job done. If WiFi range is not acceptable, then what range do you require? Ethernet is not a problem - just don’t run twisted pair cable in parallel with your mains. There’s also fiber. PLC is not an issue - there’s plenty of examples of it used on the grid. There’s also other wireless technologies like LoRa that have be used extensively.

Comment: Our meters in NZ are being converted to cellular modem.